# What is the best way for passing multiple children?

Tags: reactjs

It is clear what to do if we need to pass a list of children:

```
export const SomeWrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <div className="list-of-something">
        {children}
    </div>
);

<SomeWrapper>
    <C1 />
    <C2 />
</SomeWrapper>
```

But what is the best way to pass several children which have different parents?

```
export const SomeWrapper = ({ component1, component2 }) => (
    <div className="list-item">
        <div className="name">
            {component1}
        </div>
        <div className="whatever">
            {'Whatever'}
        </div>
        <div className="value">
            {component2}
        </div>
    </div>
);

<SomeWrapper component1={<C1 />} component2={<C2 />} />
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution. Doing this.props.children[0] and this.props.children[1] looks also weird.

What would you suggest in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice of ReactJS is to pass either a single component as the child

```
<Parent>
    <Child/>
</Parent>
```

or an array of homogeneous array as such

```
<Parent>
    [<Child key='c1'/>, <Child key='c2' />]
</Parent>
```

In your case, it is advisable not to put a container/component as a property in the parent component. Just pass in some primative values (at most a shallow plain object) as the properties in the parent, and construct the child component in that particular parent object as such:

```
//SomeWrapper
const SomeWrapper = ({c1, c2}) => (
<Parent>
  <ChildItemA title={c1.title} ... />
  <ChildItemB title='Whatever' ... />
  <ChildItemC title={c2.title} ... />
</Parent> );

//Usage
<SomeWrapper c1={c1_obj} c2={c2_obj} />
```

Comment: Passing plain objects is not gonna work here because child components can have different types. One more option is to pass a react class, properties and children of each component and make an instance using: React.createElement(class, props, children). But I don't think this approach is the best.